# C, Find the intermediate value of a define

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

Given the following defines :

```
#define foo bar
#define bar 2

#define reg_bar 4
```

I'm trying to create a macro that given the define foo, find the value of the define **reg_bar, 4**.

I tried this:

```
#define foo_bar(value) reg_##value

foo_bar(foo)
```

But it doesn't work, as it returns reg_foo.

And this

```
#define foo_bar(value) reg_##value
#define foo_bar_2(value) foo_bar(value)

foo_bar_2(foo)
```

But it still doesn't work as it returns reg_2

Is there anyway to do it, only with macro and preprocessor?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no. There is no such thing as an "intermediate value". A token sequence is either expanded or not; `##` suppresses expansion, but there is nothing which suppressed "part of" the expansion.